# layout() requires delay to changes in order to have visual changes

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to 'dynamically' create a layout in a program, but I am having issues getting the layout to change its position and size without a delay.

Code:

```
package com.example.alexander.compassvsredneckinterpretertimetable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class testActivity extends Activity
{
    class testUI
    {
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        TextView start;
        TextView end;

    int startValue, endValue;

    private ShapeDrawable makeBackgorundShape()
    {
        ShapeDrawable BackgroundShape = new ShapeDrawable();
        BackgroundShape.setShape(ItemBackground.makeRoundRect());
        BackgroundShape.getPaint().setColor(0xffa6b2fc);
        return BackgroundShape;
    }

    testUI(Context context, final ConstraintLayout parent, int startValue_, int endValue_)
    {
        this.startValue = startValue_ * 100;
        this.endValue = endValue_ * 100;

        start = new TextView(context);
        start.setText(".        " + String.valueOf(endValue) + "        .");

        end = new TextView(context);
        end.setText(".        " + String.valueOf(startValue) + "        .");

        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.addView(start);
        linearLayout.addView(end);
        linearLayout.setBackground(makeBackgorundShape());

        parent.addView(linearLayout);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
        @Override
            public void run()
            {
                linearLayout.layout(parent.getLeft(), linearLayout.getTop() + startValue, parent.getRight(), linearLayout.getBottom() + endValue); //without being postDelayed, this doesn't work
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        //handler.post(runnable); //doesn't work
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constLayout);

    new testUI(this, constraintLayout, 8, 10);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".testActivity">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

if handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); is changed to handler.post(runnable); or the handler and runnable are removed completely (just leaving the layout line), the layout doesn't change position or size at all.
I am not sure what the minimum delay is, but having the delay results in elements visibly flickering or changing position or size. Is there a way to get rid of the delay?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of changing a View's dimensions in Android is to adjust the View's `LayoutParams`. You don't want to call `layout()` directly (in this situation); it's not designed to be used in that way.

Perhaps something like this (instead of your `Runnable`):

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params;
params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
params.height = endValue - startValue;
params.topMargin = startValue;
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.connect( R.id.myLinearLayout, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.constLayout, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0 );
constraintSet.applyTo( parent );
```

In order for this to work, all of `constLayout's` children must have resource IDs. For that reason, you may find it easiest to just have them in the .xml file to begin with:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".testActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Naturally, you would find them with `findViewById()`, rather than adding them dynamically, in this case.

Comment: sorry for delay, the size is changing but the position is not?

Comment: @Null Ah, I see, the top margin doesn't work. Answer has been edited to include fix.